# Is it possible to keep changes to a public Google Sheet clientside only?

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I've created a list in Google Sheets that lets the user easily apply custom filters by either entering a search term or selecting an item per column as well as sort by some criteria. Since the document is supposed to be used by multiple people without Google accounts, I'd like anyone to be able to browse the list and apply criteria as straightforward as using Filter Views. However, if I were to publish the spreadsheet as it is now, the filter settings would naturally apply to every viewer of the document.

Is it possible to let viewers use the filters without manipulating the results for the others?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well, for that purpose alone, there was created the **"black filter view"**

[image: 0]

---

which is local and does not influence original dataset at all, as it does the **"green filter view"** which acts as global for all users

[image: 0]

---

so now the only obstacle is unawareness of this, of the majority Google Sheet users because black filter view needs to be triggered by each user on his side.

Comment: I know about filter views and have been using them, but they have major drawbacks: you can only apply one at once, you can only sort the values of a single column, the range doesn't dynamically update with increased length, and while you can create custom ones it requires the viewer to have some experience with the tool. I was hoping I could use my self-made filter to make advanced searches easy for anyone, but it doesn't seem like Google Sheets supports what would be necessary for my solution to work.

Comment: well, hence those "obstacles". unfortunately, this is your only option